# python urllib2 can open localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, proxy, localhost, urllib2

I am using python `urllib2` library and can see a strange and nasty problem.

**Windows 7.**

My code:

```
import urllib2 as url_request


opener = url_request.build_opener(url_request.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://login:password@server:8080'}))
request = url_request.Request("http://localhost");
response = opener.open(request)
print response.read()
```

It works perfectly well, but when I change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` this error happens:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  )
```

**Another addresses like google.com can be opened sucessfully.
The only problem is 127.0.0.1**

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you sending the request through a proxy if you are trying to access your local machine?

Comment: browser open 127.0.0.1 successfuly. Page is the same as on localhost.

Comment: If it works with 'localhost' then why change it? a.k.a "if it ain't broke then don't fix it" ;-)

Comment: I need 127.0.0.1 work ok, because I am using third-party library which do the same stuff with 127.0.0.1 and error is happening all the time.

Comment: How about setting `no_proxy` to `127.0.0.1` then?

Answer (score 7):

Set a `no_proxy` or `NO_PROXY` environment key with `127.0.0.1`, optionally with `localhost` too:

```
import os

os.environ['no_proxy'] = '127.0.0.1,localhost'
```

On Windows the `ProxyOverride` key in the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` registry is consulted as well, you probably have `localhost` registered as exception. Check your proxy settings to verify this.